# tkinter widgets not showing in frame widgets

Tags: tkinter, button, widget, frame, display

I am trying to make a GUI in python using the Tkinter library. I have used classes so that I can set up uniform-looking buttons and frames. the issue I am having is when I place, pack or grid the buttons into the frame, the widgets aren't been displayed. I am trying to have playback widgets that will be displayed in the controls widget.

```py
import tkinter as tk

HEIGHT = 457
WIDTH = 600
MAIN_COLOR = '#0e2625'
FG_COLOR = 'white'


photo = []


def playing():
    print('is playing')


# Create a frame framework
class Frames(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, name, master, width, height, color=MAIN_COLOR, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.name = name
        self.master = master
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color

        self.frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.master, text=self.name, width=self.width, height=self.height, bg=self.color)
        self.frame['foreground'] = FG_COLOR

    def grid(self, row, column, rowspan=None, columnspan=None):
        self.frame.grid(row=row, column=column, rowspan=rowspan, columnspan=columnspan, padx=5)


# class to use as blueprint for buttons
class Buttons(tk.Button):
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self, name, master, command, image, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.master = master
        self.command = command
        self.ref = Buttons.counter

        global photo

        img = tk.PhotoImage(file=self.image)
        img = img.subsample(5, 5)

        photo.append(img)
        self.name = tk.Button(self.master, text=name, command=command, width=10, image=photo[self.ref], compound='left')

        Buttons.counter += 1


# configuring the root screen

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('PlayR')
root.configure(bg=MAIN_COLOR)

screen = str(WIDTH) + 'x' + str(HEIGHT)
root.geometry(screen)
root.resizable(False, False)


detail_frame = Frames('detail', root, (WIDTH / 2) - 10, 350)
detail_frame.grid(0, 0, 1, 1)

image_frame = Frames('cover', root, (WIDTH / 2) - 10, 350)
image_frame.grid(0, 1, 1, 1)

control_frame = Frames('controls', root, WIDTH - 20, 100)
control_frame.grid(1, 0, 1, 2)


play = Buttons('play', control_frame, playing, 'Assets/play-button-arrowhead.png')
play.grid(row=0, column=0)

pause = Buttons('pause', control_frame, playing, 'Assets/pause.png')
pause.grid(row=0, column=1)

stop = Buttons('stop', control_frame, playing, 'Assets/stop.png')
stop.grid(row=0, column=2)

prev = Buttons('prev', control_frame, playing, 'Assets/previous.png')
prev.grid(row=0, column=3)

play_next = Buttons('next', control_frame, playing, 'Assets/next.png')
play_next.grid(row=0, column=4 )

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You know that when you call the `Frames.__init__` method you create 2 `tk.LabelFrame`s right?

Comment: Also you don't need to have `global photo` because it is a mutable object.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using inheritance properly. Let's look at this code:

```
# Create a frame framework
class Frames(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, name, master, width, height, color=MAIN_COLOR, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        ...
        self.frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.master, text=self.name, width=self.width, height=self.height, bg=self.color)
```

This creates *two* frame widgets. The instance itself (`self`) is a `LabelFrame`, and `self.frame` is another labelframe.

Later, you create an instance of this class named `detail_frame` and you put a button in it. The button is a child of `detail_frame` *not* the inner frame `self.frame`. Since your custom `grid` method works upon `self.frame` rather than `self`, `detail_frame` is never added to the root so it and all of its children are invisible.

The proper solution is to *not* create `self.frame`. It's completely unnecessary for what you're trying to do since `self` is already a frame. You also don't need to override the `grid` command since you aren't adding any value.

You make the same mistake with the `Buttons` class. It creates two buttons when it should only be creating one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've never really wrapped my head around inheritance and its now just starting to make sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

# Well done on setting up constants
HEIGHT = 457
WIDTH = 600
MAIN_COLOR = '#0e2625'
FG_COLOR = 'white'


def playing():
    print('is playing')


# Create a frame framework
class Frames(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, color=MAIN_COLOR, **kwargs):
        self.color = color

        super().__init__(self.master, bg=self.color, fg=FG_COLOR, **kwargs)

    def grid(self, **kwargs):
        # Use kwargs because later you will forget the order of your args.
        # Try it now: was it (row, column) or (column, row)
        super().grid(padx=5, **kwargs)


# class to use as blueprint for buttons
class Buttons(tk.Button):
    # Master always goes first (tkinter convention)
    def __init__(self, master, image, width=10, **kwargs):
        self.image = image

        # This is a better way of keeping a reference of the image
        self.img = tk.PhotoImage(file=self.image)
        self.img = self.img.subsample(5, 5)

        super().__init__(master, width=width, image=self.img, compound='left', **kwargs)



# configuring the root screen

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('PlayR')
root.configure(bg=MAIN_COLOR)

screen = str(WIDTH) + 'x' + str(HEIGHT)
root.geometry(screen)
root.resizable(False, False)


control_frame = Frames(root, text='controls', width=WIDTH - 20, height=100)
control_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

play = Buttons(control_frame, text='play', command=playing, image='img.png')
play.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

As @BryanOakley said you aren't using inheritance properly. Also your code is not pythonic. I think I made it more pythonic and I think it works now.

Comment: `self.master = master` inside `Frames.__init__()` is not necessary because every tkinter widget, `self.master` is implicitly created.

Comment: @acw1668 True thx. I removed `self.master = master` from the other class but forgot that one :D.

Comment: You are right. this is much easier to read and looks a whole lot nicer. Thank you

Comment: @kayongofwoloshi If you want your code to look better read [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).